# Spawning sprites on an interval and prevent them to overlap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, there is a ball that we control and this ball changes its color after it passes through a wall. The wall is formed 3 parts which are red, blue and yellow. The play of the game works like flappy bird. It is an infinite game which you have to pass through the same color as the ball. I put the walls into different layers and made them a prefab.

Here is my code to spawn parts of the wall:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
     
public class deployWalls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject blue;
    public GameObject yellow;
    public GameObject red;
    public float rewpawnTime=1.0f;
    private Vector2 screenBounds;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (Screen.width,Screen.height,Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        StartCoroutine(wallWave());
    }

    private void spawnWall()
    {
        GameObject b = Instantiate(blue) as GameObject;
        GameObject y = Instantiate(yellow) as GameObject;
        GameObject r = Instantiate(red) as GameObject;
        b.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x *-2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
        y.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x *-2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
        r.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x *-2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
    }
    
    IEnumerator wallWave()
    {
        while(true){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            spawnWall();
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the game the wall parts spawn:

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q3ng.png)

However they should be in an interval which is total length of these 3 parts, and they should not overlap.Also the order of the colors should be changed.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQY7j.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are completely randomizing the position of the walls on the screen

```
b.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x *-2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
y.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x *-2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
r.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x *-2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
```

What you need to do is randomize the order of the colors firstly. Also we need the height of the wall

```
float wallHeight = 5; //arbitrary number for example purpose

int orderBlue = 0;
int orderRed = 0;
int orderYellow = 0;

do {
colorBlue = Random.Range(0, 2);
colorRed = Random.Range(0, 2);
colorYellow = Random.Range(0, 2);
} while ((orderBlue == orderRed) || (orderBlue == orderYellow) || (orderRed = orderYellow))
```

Determine which color is first then add the other walls underneath

```
if (colorBlue == 2) {
b.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x *-2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
if (colorYellow == 1) {
y.transform.position = new Vector2(b.transform.position.x, b.transform.position.y - wallHeight);
r.transform.position = new Vector2(b.transform.position.x, b.transform.position.y - 2 * wallHeight);
}
if (colorRed == 1) {
r.transform.position = new Vector2(b.transform.position.x, b.transform.position.y - wallHeight);
y.transform.position = new Vector2(b.transform.position.x, b.transform.position.y - 2 * wallHeight);
}
}

if (colorRed == 2) {
// add same code as above but switch colors
}

if (colorYellow == 2) {
// add same code as above but switch colors    
}
```

Comment: how can I get height of the wall

Comment: you can try r.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().size.y; after you initialize r, also you can try r.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().size.y , I'm not sure how your prefab is set up, you can also experiement with setting the float in the inspector and seeing what works if the above doesnt work, just add public infront of wallHeight